# Trigger a function in a controller with Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

In an angular controller I have a function on my scope that looks like this:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(val) {
$scope.myVar = val;
$scope.mySettings.myPath = $scope.myBase + $scope.myVar;
}
```

In my karma unit test I want to trigger that function on the controller using a value i supply ... then check $scope.mySettings.myPath to make sure it is what i think it should be.

Im trying this in karma:

```
describe("Unit Testing: Controller Testing" , function() {
describe('myController' , function () {
var scope,ctrl;

beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
scope = $rootScope.$new();
ctrl = $controller('myController', {
$scope: scope
});
}));

it('should have a working changeVideo function' , function(){
scope.changeVideo(scope.myVar[6]);
expect(scope.mySettings.myPath).to.equal('Expected String');
});
});
});
```

The error i see is that it cannot call equal method of undefined. Which is odd because scope.mySettings.myPath is actually predefined in the controller so it should never be undefined.

To give some background I do have access to the controller and the scope from karma. This one is stumping me though.

Comment: Can you post the full test?

Comment: Isn't it `toEqual()`? Or simply `toBe()`

Comment: i posted an edit with a more complete test

Comment: JB you were correct ... toEqual() not to.equal() ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was using toEqual() instead of to.equal()